# Trouble installing wine64

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, wine

I have searched everywhere in the internet to solve this problem but even through those I could not get these errors to go away:

```
sudo apt-get install wine64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine64 : Depends: libwine (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: wine32 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install the missing package libwine and I got this error:

```
sudo apt-get install libwine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libwine : Depends: libvkd3d1 (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I tried to install **that** missing package and got ***this*** error:

```
sudo apt-get install libvkd3d1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libvkd3d1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 is to be installed
         Depends: libvkd3d-shader1 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I gave up. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Try doing `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update` then re-run `sudo apt-get install wine64`. If that doesn't work, open your Software Updater app from your app tray. Let it check for updates. Install updates if prompted to. Then re-run `sudo apt-get install wine64`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages). Before you add new software, your system needs to be up-to-date and your package manager can not have problems. You can't add new software because your package manager has problems. You need to run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade` - both of these commands need to come back "clean" before you add anything new.

Comment: Check your sources; as libc6 is `2.31-0ubuntu9.9` for *focal* (20.04), so you've likely added 3rd party sources built for/from later releases that have caused the errors you're experiencing.  You've given `apt-cache policy` details of where you're getting packages, but I'd check your `apt update` for non-focal sources as likely causes.